# How to install net6's iOS workload in Azure DevOps?

Tags: ios, .net, azure, azure-pipelines, .net-6.0

I have an iOS application built using `Xamarin.iOS`.

I am in the process of migrating the application to `.net6`.

To be able to build my application locally, I obviously need `.net6`'s SDK installed and I also need to install the iOS workload which is done using the following command:

```
dotnet install workload ios
```

Now, when I try to build the application in Azure DevOps using a macOS machine, it fails:

```
error NETSDK1147: To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload install ios [/Users/runner/work/1/s/src/Application.iOS/Application.iOS.csproj]
```

**Question**

What is the recommended way to install the `.net6`'s iOS workload in Azure DevOps?

[image: Pipeline]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much simpler than I originally thought. I used a Bash task and simply ran the following inlined command:

```
dotnet workload install ios
```

[image: Screenshot of the DevOps page]

Answer (score 4):

In YAML piplines this can be done using the `dotnet` task with a custom command:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Install .net iOS workflow"
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'workload'
    arguments: 'install ios'
```